# Oracle DB table or view does not exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm trying to connect a Oracle database to my JAVA web project.
and when creating the connection to the database using system user connection is successfully established.

But when I execute a simple select * command in the connection it says

Error code 942, SQL state 42000: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

These sql queries work in sqldeveloper. No errors.

I'm using oracle 10g thin client ojdbc6 driver and jdk 1.7

what can be the problem?

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Error Code: 942
Call: SELECT USERID, FULLNAME, USERNAME, USER_CREDENTIALSID, USER_TYPEID FROM USERS
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Users sql="SELECT USERID, FULLNAME, USERNAME, USER_CREDENTIALSID, USER_TYPEID FROM USERS")
```

Comment: Please post the code that results in your error.

Comment: Are you connecting as the same user as you connected with in sqldeveloper? This error usually results from you not having select permission or the table is in another schema and there are no synonyms.

Comment: yes I'm connecting as the same user system. also tried connecting using hr. but it didn't solve the problem. and the Table is in the same schema.

Comment: Try this query: SELECT OWNER,TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'USERS';

Comment: it gives the result OWNER - JPAMAGAZINE, TABLE_NAME - USERS

Comment: @RajithShanika can you change your table name as _JPAMAGAZINE.USERS_ ?

Comment: for me the same problem occur due to schema name....I just change the schema name and it's working fine for me...hope this will helpful to for some one else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was connecting as the system user. I saw an account in oracle administration page called JPAMAGAZINE. connected using that account and it worked.